# How do I increase the fontsize of the text along circular path?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to increase the fontsize of English Learning Center, Designing Center  without changing the size of the circles.
[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
    \usepackage{tikz, pgfornament, tikzrput}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,decorations, decorations.text}
    \usepackage[textwidth=5cm,textheight=5cm,right=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    % font size
    \usepackage{fix-cm}
    % cryillic font
   \usepackage[OT2, OT1]{fontenc}
   \newcommand\cyr{%
    \renewcommand\rmdefault{wncyr}%
    \renewcommand\sfdefault{wncyss}%
    \renewcommand\encodingdefault{OT2}%
    \normalfont
    \selectfont
    }
   \DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcyr}{\cyr}
   \def\Eoborotnoye{\char3}
   \def\eoborotnoye{\char11}
   \def\cprime{\char126}
   \def\cdprime{\char127}

  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   %%%% Text along circular path
   % outer circle
        \draw[line width=0.5 mm] circle[radius=9 cm];
    % inner circles
        \draw[ultra thick]  circle[radius=7.3 cm]  ;
    % outer text
        \path[
            %rotate=-15.2,
            postaction={
                decoration={
                    text along path,
                    text format delimiters={|}{|},
                    text={%
                        |\bfseries\HUGE|                            
                          Designing Center 
                    },
                    text align=center,
                    reverse path
                },
                decorate
            }
        ]
      (20:7.8cm) arc (20:160:7.8cm); %   (-27:6.2cm) arc (-27:210:6.2cm);   
    \path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, text align=fit to path,text={|\bfseries\HUGE|English Learning Center}}}] (209:8.4cm) arc (209:330:8.4cm); %%(209:6.8cm) arc (209:330:6.8cm);
     % central text
       \node[font=\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont] at (0, 0.5){{ E L C}};
     \end{tikzpicture}         

     \end{document}
```

Comment: Determine font size similar as for "ECL". For example `text={%
                        |\fontsize{42}{44}\selectfont\bfseries|
                          Designing Center
                    },` works fine.

Comment: @Zarko Could you post an answer?

Comment: @CarLaTeX, done! Thank you for encourage me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Font size you can determine by `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont` as you use for determining it size for centering position. So, as I suggest in comment you can instead

```
text={|\bfseries\HUGE| Designing Center},
```

use

```
text={|\fontsize{42}{44}\selectfont\bfseries| Designing Center},
```

Complete code with some small changes in comparison to your MWE (for making MWE more concise and consistent) is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.text}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% font size
\usepackage{fix-cm}
% cryillic font
\usepackage[OT2, OT1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}
%%%% Text along circular path
% outer circle
    \draw[line width=0.5 mm] circle[radius=9 cm];
% inner circles with central text
    \draw[ultra thick]  circle[radius=7.3 cm] 
        node[font=\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\bfseries] {E L C};% moved here, changed font shape
% outer text
\path[postaction={decoration={
                    text along path,
                    text format delimiters={|}{|},
                    text={|\fontsize{42}{44}\selectfont\bfseries| Designing Center},
                    text align=center,
                    reverse path
                            },
      decorate}]    (20:7.75cm) arc (20:160:7.75cm);
\path [postaction={decoration={
                    text along path, 
                    text align=fit to path,
                    text={|\fontsize{42}{44}\selectfont\bfseries| English Learning Center}
                            },
      decorate}]    (209:8.5cm) arc (209:330:8.5cm); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

*Note:*
In your MWE you have terrible discrepancy to defined page layout and size of image (image is far bigger than text area). This is a reason why I didn't use `memouir` as document class nor page layout defined by parameters of the `geometry` package.