# How to write hindi circular text in latex?

Tags: fonts, tikz-styles, text

I was unable to write hindi circular text, the text becomes straight line, while it gives circular text for english.

See Previous question

[How do I increase the fontsize of the text along circular path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368436/how-do-i-increase-the-fontsize-of-the-text-along-circular-path)

for an English example.

Comment: This is clearly an unclear question. Please add a MWE.

Comment: You've posted enough queries by now on this site to be fully aware of the importance of providing a minimum (non)working example (MWE). Do show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very unclear however if I take the example from your previous question and translate the text to Hindi (or whatever google translate says is hindi) I get

[image]

using xelatex.

The main problem here is that in splitting up one character at a time to add the curvature, the macros have broken up the combining character combinations leaving floating combinations that probably render the text unreadable.

That is fixable by grouping each letter that you want to stay in one piece in `{}` so instead of

```
hello world
```

use

```
he{ll}o world
```

if you want to keep the `ll` together.

I made an attempt and got the following but I may have completely destroyed the text as I can not read it before or after this edit.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
    \usepackage{tikz, pgfornament, tikzrput}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,decorations, decorations.text}
    \usepackage[textwidth=17cm,textheight=17cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    % font size
    \usepackage{fix-cm}
    % cryillic font
   \usepackage[OT2, OT1]{fontenc}

   \def\Eoborotnoye{\char3}
   \def\eoborotnoye{\char11}
   \def\cprime{\char126}
   \def\cdprime{\char127}

  \pagenumbering{gobble}

\newfontface{\hindi}[Script=Devanagari]{Nirmala UI}

  \begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   %%%% Text along circular path
   % outer circle
        \draw[line width=0.5 mm] circle[radius=9 cm];
    % inner circles
        \draw[ultra thick]  circle[radius=7.3 cm]  ;
    % outer text
        \path[
            %rotate=-15.2,
            postaction={
                decoration={
                    text along path,
                    text format delimiters={|}{|},
                    text={%
                        |\bfseries\HUGE\hindi|                            
                          {डि}{जा}{इ}{निं}{ग} {कें}{द्र}{}
                    },
                    text align=center,
                    reverse path
                },
                decorate
            }
        ]
      (20:7.8cm) arc (20:160:7.8cm); %   (-27:6.2cm) arc (-27:210:6.2cm);   
    \path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, text align=fit to path,
text={|\bfseries\HUGE\hindi|{अं}{ग्रे}{जी} {सी}{ख}{ना}{} {कें}{द्र}{}}}}] (209:8.4cm) arc (209:330:8.4cm); %%(209:6.8cm) arc (209:330:6.8cm);
     % central text
       \node[font=\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont] at (0, 0.5){{ E L C}};
     \end{tikzpicture}         

     \end{document}
```

Comment: The text is fine! (In the second version.) It may not meet the highest standards of typography as for example the top bars of the letters don't join each other (as they do when not curved) and there are tiny gaps… but I don't expect TeX or TikZ to be able to handle this; probably the font designer would have to specify such shapes. And I don't think there's any existing software that does that anyway.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR thanks for the confirmation, it's a bit like editing with your eyes shut so glad it's not complete nonsense:-)

Comment: @BikiTeron next time please provide an example, I never could guess what you had actually done to make the Hindi text straight not curved, the only problem I saw was the combining characters.

Comment: Next time i will try to provide my minimal coding sir. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @BikiTeron : -)